# Azure AD B2B users not seeing tenant branding

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a multi-tenant application where I added external B2B users via the graph (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations).  The tenant in which the application belongs is branded with the customer's branding.  When logging in as one of these external users the branding disappears.  The external users log into the application just fine, we're just having issues with the branding.

I'm guessing that it has to do with the tenant discovery because if I modify the OWIN not to use the LoginHint property the branding appears until I add the external user's email address into the user field.  I have tried setting the DomainHint property to the domain with the branding with no luck.

Is there any way I can override the tenant discovery to show the branding?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A branded sign-in page only appears when you visit an application with a tenant-specific URL such as https://outlook.com/contoso.com, or https://mail.contoso.com.

When you visit a service with non-tenant specific URLs (e.g.: https://mail.office365.com), a non-branded sign-in page appears. in this case, your branding appears once you have entered your user ID or you have selected a user tile.

Therefore, my understanding is that the Endpoint can redirect to the sign-in page based on the URL or user ID, and this can cause the B2B user to access the sign-in page without branding.